# Calling lua from a c program get a nil value (global 'pcall')

Tags: c, lua

here is lua code:

```
function calc (x, y)
    return (x^2 * y)
end

pcall(calc,10,20)
```

when i run dofile get error:attempt to call a nil value (global 'pcall')
my lua version is lua5.4.0
how can i fix this problem

Comment: There is no function called pcall. Probably because your C code did not create one. Probably because you did not call the C function that creates it (luaL_openlibs)

Comment: Your program runs fine in the [Lua demo](https://www.lua.org/demo.html).

Answer (score 1):

Ok.I have fixed it already.I called clua_hide_pcall before dofile,My mistake...
Thanks for anwser my question!